# React rendering non react-dom

Tags: reactjs

if react-dom is specifically geared for rendering html elements and react-native renders native views...
Lets say I have an xml type language and I want to use react / jsx to declaratively compose components that have there own native elements.

- How do I create base elements (not divs or spans but something else)
- How can I get a react component to run its lifecycle method without using ReactDom.render
- any resources out there that I can study?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would look into this: https://github.com/SilentCicero/yoyo-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the [tutorial](https://github.com/nitin42/Making-a-custom-React-renderer) by Nitin Tulswani on writing a custom react renderer.